# How to make pyramid programs in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to make a pyramid program in `PHP` like this :

```
    1
   21
  321
 4321
54321
```

I tried this :

```
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
{
    for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++)
    {
        echo $j;
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

But it is creating a pyramid like this :

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

I am trying this for the last 6 hours but couldn't make that.
Can anyone please help me in doing that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://php.net/str_pad

Comment: No it is not. I am trying to develop my logics that's y I am doing this but i am unable to make that that's y i asked for help.

Comment: [It works just fine for me...](http://codepad.viper-7.com/iSnqI1)

Comment: @brbcoding the one you are showing as working, i already created that, but i want the one at the top in my question.

Comment: My apologies. I read it backwards. I thought the top one was the output you wanted and the bottom was the output you received. **Wednesdays** :-/

Comment: Hang in there. It's almost the weekend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little more creativity:

```
$width = 9;

foreach (range(1, $width) as $i) {
    printf("%{$width}s\n", join(array_reverse(range(1, $i))));
}
```

http://3v4l.org/rFB0Y

Comment: But really most likely this is a homework assignment as he can't submit that as a solution. So I'll give you an upvote too.

Answer (score 2):

```
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
{
    for($j=5; $j>$i; $j--)
    {
        echo "&nbsp;";
    }
    for($j=$i; $j>0; $j--)
    {
        echo $j;
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: It is not working. I want the position of 1st 1 at the end of 1st line, it is having 1 at the beginning of 1st line

Comment: Works just fine for me.

Comment: Are you outputting this in a browser?

Comment: Change the space to `&nbsp;` and use a fixed-width font. Browsers remove duplicate spaces automatically.

Comment: Let's see the page where you are outputting this.

Comment: Here. http://codepad.viper-7.com/cBvAGw You only need to make sure your font is fixed width.

Comment: it just needed one more &nbsp; and it is perfect. http://codepad.viper-7.com/kcMZnM. Thank you so much

Comment: That's only a coincidence that two spaces are the same width as numbers in that font. If you change your font it will break.

Comment: This is not a homework ok.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want :) ?

```
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
{
    $string = null;
    for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++)
    {
        $string .= $j;
    }
    echo strrev($string) . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my contribution:

```
$o = '';
echo "<pre>";

for($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++)
{
    $o .= $i;
    for($x = 0; $x < 5-$i; $x++)
        echo " ";
    echo $o . "\n";
}

echo "</pre>";
```

[Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/3yON52)

Comment: It is creating different pyramid than i want

Comment: Oh sorry, thats an easy fix, and here is also with comparesion.
http://codepad.viper-7.com/B4FYnz

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=1;$i!=6;$i++)
{
    for ($z = 5-$i; $z != 0; $z--) {
        echo "&nbsp;";
    }

    for ($z = $i; $z > 0; $z--) {
        echo $z;
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: That is not the best code.

Comment: That's quite the edit ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$cnt    = 5;
$array  = array_fill(0, ($cnt), '0');

for($i=1;$i<($cnt+1);$i++){
    array_shift($array);
    array_push($array, $i);
    echo implode(" ", $array);
    echo "<br>";
}
```

To get a better view I added `0` instead of `space`, to get Space change `$array  = array_fill(0, ($cnt-1), '0');` to `$array  = array_fill(0, ($cnt-1), '&nbsp;');`

Output :

```
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 2
0 0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($r=1; $s>=$r; r++)
 {
   for($p=$s-$r; $p>=1; $p--)
      echo(" ");

   for($c=1; c<=$r; c++)
      print_r($c);

   for($x=$r-1; $x>=1; x--)
     print_r($x);

 }
```

Comment: Can you explain more about your code?